# Where can I ask software developing troubleshooting questions?

Tags: discussion

I need to ask a some question about troubleshooting, such as:

> An application instance is working, but it doesn't respond on HTTP requests.
>   What should I do first and second? (I awaiting answers like which tools to use, which logs to see, etc.)

I feel the main site Stack Overflow is not an appropriate place for troubleshooting questions (I think it mainly for software developing, but maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: Common sense, friend. The first and second thing you need to do is apply common sense. Because whatever the problem is: it is **not** black magic, has nothing to do with the alignment of the stars and it is not the universe working against you personally. it is something silly and overlooked. Wrong port, wrong path, firewall, NAT rule, security setting, whatever. The only thing that can be done about it is - look, look more, rubber duck, look more. Until you find it and then you laugh about how you could overlook something so silly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There really isn't any site in the network which can give you tips on **what** to troubleshoot, because troubleshooting is too nebulous a concept to pin down.